# web.config redirect in IIS server

Tags: iis, iis-7, web-config

I have to redirect from a domain to another.
I try different ways to do this but it doesn't work.
Someone can tell me the right metod to do a redirect in web.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the ways you tried, I would suggest setting up a Global URL Rewrite rule, you do this at the server level not the individual web site level.

These setting will be stored in the applicationhost.config (Server level), not the (web.config)

Below will redirect `example2.com` to `example.com`

```
<rule name="Redirect to new domain" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example2\.com$" />
             </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.eample.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```